# Using Python, BeautifulSoup, CSV to scrape a URL

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

In this URL **https://doc8643.com/aircrafts**  I want to scrape all rows.

Then for each individual row, for example **https://doc8643.com/aircraft/A139**
I want to scrape these three areas of data

```
<table class="table centered-table"> 
<h4>Manufacturers</h4>
<h4>Technical Data</h4>
```

Can this is done in python?

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request

url = 'https://doc8643.com/aircrafts'
req = Request(url , headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'})

with open('doc8643.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    while True:
        print(url)
        html = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

        # Go throught table = tbody and extract the data under the 'td' tag
        for row in soup.select('ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked li.aircraft_item'):
            writer.writerow([c.text if c.text else '' for c in row.select('h3')])
            print(row)

        # If more than one page then iterate through all of them        
        if soup.select_one('ul.pagination li.active + li a'):
            url = soup.select_one('ul.pagination li.active + li a')['href']
        else:
            break
```

Comment: You forgot to ask your question.

Comment: what is your problem? Maybe first create function which scrapes details from subpage and later use it inside your loop `for row ...`.

Comment: when I run code and display `html.text` then I see long JavaScript code instead of rows with data - probably it tries to detect bots - so it may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: if I uses module `requests` instead of `urllib.request` then I get HTML with data instead of JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You should create function which get value `c.text` (ie, `A139`) and creates full url like `https://doc8643.com/aircraft/A139` and runs `Request` or `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` to get all needs data

```
def scrape_details(number):
    url = 'https://doc8643.com/aircraft/' + number
    print('details:', url)
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    # ... scrape details and put in list `results` ...

    return results
```

and run it in your loop

```
        for row in soup.select('ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked li.aircraft_item'):
            data = [c.text if c.text else '' for c in row.select('h3')]
            for item in data:
                values = scrape_details(item)
                writer.writerow([item] + values)
```

---

The biggest problem is to scrape details.

For some details it needs to scrape `dl` and next all `dt` and `dd` and use `zip()` to group in pairs.

Something like

```
def scrape_details(number):
    url = 'https://doc8643.com/aircraft/' + number
    print('details:', url)
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    results = []

    all_dl = soup.find_all('dl')

    for item in all_dl:
        all_dt = item.find_all('dt')
        all_dd = item.find_all('dd')
        for dt, dd in zip(all_dt, all_dd):
            pair = f"{dt.string}: {dd.string}" 
            results.append(pair)
            print(pair)

    #print(results)

    return results
```

but this need more code - and I skip this part.

---

Minimal working code

**EDIT:** I added `url = 'https://doc8643.com' + url`

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36'}

# --- functions ---

def scrape_details(number):
    url = 'https://doc8643.com/aircraft/' + number
    print('details:', url)
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    results = []
    
    all_dl = soup.find_all('dl')
    
    for item in all_dl:
        all_dt = item.find_all('dt')
        all_dd = item.find_all('dd')
        for dt, dd in zip(all_dt, all_dd):
            pair = f"{dt.string}: {dd.string}"
            results.append(pair)
            print(pair)

    #print(results)

    return results

# --- main ---

url = 'https://doc8643.com/aircrafts'

with open('doc8643.csv', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["data1", "data2", "data3", "etc..."])

    while True:
        print('url:', url)
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        # Go throught table = tbody and extract the data under the 'td' tag
        for row in soup.select('ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked li.aircraft_item'):
            data = [c.text if c.text else '' for c in row.select('h3')]
            for item in data:
                values = scrape_details(item)
                writer.writerow([item] + values)

        # If more than one page then iterate through all of them        
        if soup.select_one('ul.pagination li.active + li a'):
            url = soup.select_one('ul.pagination li.active + li a')['href']
            url = 'https://doc8643.com' + url
        else:
            break
```

---

**BTW:**

Maybe it would be better to keep `results` as dictionary

```
results[dt.string] = [dd.string]
```

Comment: Hello Furas, the output file is indeed somewhat unfriendly. In the present form, the first 50 rows or records are captured. The pagination might not be looping through or perhaps in this case it done through the loading itself <div id="infscr-loading" style="display: none;"><img alt="Loading..." src="/static/img/loading.gif"><div>Loading more aircraft...</div></div>

Comment: @James it meams it use JavaScript to load data and `requests`+`Beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScript. It may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript. Or you may try to use `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` to see what URL is used by JavaScript to get data - and then you can use it with `requests`. Often it may get values as JSON so it doesn't need to scrape data from HTML.  I didn't check this problem because question was how to get details from links.

Comment: @James when I turn off JavaScript in web browser then it display links to next pages but it gives relative URL and it need to add `url = 'https://doc8643.com' + url` to get absolut url. I added  it to code in answer.

Comment: This is very useful. It seems that the "else: break " is not working since the output repeats every 2600 rows, and omitting records after WH4 which in on page doc8643.com/aircrafts/52. So from (WHAT) to (ZZZZ)or from doc8643.com/aircrafts/53 to doc8643.com/aircrafts/54 are missing. this makes little sense to me.